# Json data to a table to be echoed on a form

Tags: php, json

I have searched for weeks for an answer to this I have json data that I need to echo to the page and to auto fill a form based on the button pushed next to that name. here is a list of code that I have 
Json

```html
$url = 'http://***.***.***.***:30120/players.json'; 
// path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
// put the contents of the file into a variable
$players = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed

<?php foreach ($players as $players) : ?>
          <tr>
           <td>   
                                   <button>Ban</button>
                                   <td input type="hidden" name="user" value="user"><?php echo $players->name; ?></td>
           <td input type="hidden" name="id0" value="id0"><?php echo $players->identifiers[0]; ?></td>
           <td input type="hidden" name="id1" value="id1"><?php echo $players->identifiers[1]; ?></td>
           </td>
           </tr>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Gives me this

https://gyazo.com/e72aee4c977e9226f2de3a2053f89c2f

and I want it to auto fill a form with the players name.

or something like this

```html
function getpnames()
{
    $url = 'http://***.***.***.***:30120/players.json'; // path to your JSON file
    $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
    $players = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed
    $site = BASE_URL;
    
      

    $result = json_decode($data);

    echo '
        <table id="allUsers" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Steam ID</th>
            <th>License</th>
            <th>Banned Player</th>
            <th>Admin</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Perm?</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    ';

    while ($row = http_build_query($result, '', ';'))
    {
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $row[1] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row[2] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row[3] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row[4] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row[5] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row[6] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row[7] . '</td>
            <td>
                <form action="'.$site.'/actions/adminActions.php" method="post">
                <input name="deleteBan" type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" onclick="deleteBan(' . $row[0] . ')" value="Delete" />
                ';
       
        echo '

                <input name="bid" type="hidden" value=' . $row[0] . ' />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }

    echo '
        </tbody>
        </table>
    ';

}
```

I cant seem to wrap my head around this

Json Data

> [{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":206,"identifiers":["steam:1100001366011b6","license:"],"name":"Bonsan905","ping":21},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":183,"identifiers":["steam:11000010b7f88b5","license:","xbl:2535467507102211","live:844425221417841"],"name":"Jonathan J.","ping":34},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":190,"identifiers":["steam:110000110be22ca","license:","xbl:2535451382352605","live:1899947295907508"],"name":"[TT-AMRA III] Aqua","ping":47},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":135,"identifiers":["steam:1100001161c23dc","license:","xbl:2535429725972000","live:914802232166266"],"name":"Norank.","ping":19},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":160,"identifiers":["steam:110000106d4e97c","license:","xbl:2535436731105061","live:844428383945858"],"name":"Max W.","ping":66},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":181,"identifiers":["steam:11000010a812251","license:","xbl:2535415227958286","live:1688853869063259"],"name":"Filippen","ping":40},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":202,"identifiers":["steam:110000134bddbd7","license:","xbl:2535453098180945","live:914802201806712"],"name":"VAC_brotha","ping":44},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":243,"identifiers":["steam:1100001351ef803","license:","xbl:2533274991210897","live:985156970449557"],"name":"Allan [S-662]","ping":177},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":218,"identifiers":["steam:11000010ad8b0bf","license:","xbl:2533274880694377","live:1759221802890599"],"name":"Katie Kat","ping":166},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":184,"identifiers":["steam:11000010be231cc","license:","xbl:2533275012889196","live:1759222203382981"],"name":"High Budget Trucker T-69","ping":55},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":244,"identifiers":["steam:110000115f03632","license:"],"name":"John Adams","ping":72},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":223,"identifiers":["steam:11000010bb69ddd","license:","live:1899943264922053"],"name":"[S853] Johnathen [1Z13]","ping":45},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":216,"identifiers":["steam:11000011cb29587","license:"],"name":"Steve","ping":198},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":203,"identifiers":["steam:1100001076829a3","license:","xbl:2535446122759170","live:1055521739595821"],"name":"Hoopsure","ping":152},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":226,"identifiers":["steam:1100001359fd857","license:"],"name":"[S-894] EpicDogePlayzYT","ping":183},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":236,"identifiers":["steam:11000010d29c185","license:"],"name":"Night","ping":24},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":193,"identifiers":["steam:1100001183e1fa8","license:"],"name":"J.W","ping":201},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":219,"identifiers":["steam:11000013559122f","license:"],"name":"[S-885]*Damien.B*","ping":61},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":187,"identifiers":["steam:110000108413e7a","license:","xbl:2535423985280873","live:985156647647394"],"name":"Purple Deathh","ping":18},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":130,"identifiers":["steam:110000113e184ad","license:","xbl:2535441445938947","live:844428429722616"],"name":"JamiDoesStuff","ping":23},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":205,"identifiers":["steam:11000011a84d2dc","license:"],"name":"Johnny","ping":45},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":231,"identifiers":["steam:1100001065ace8a","license:"],"name":"unicornassassin","ping":147},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":166,"identifiers":["steam:110000113334071","license:","xbl:2535468344890625","live:1759222493808119"],"name":"ItsQeeqo","ping":21},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":225,"identifiers":["steam:1100001119c6bdc","license:"],"name":"Pizza Parker","ping":74},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":238,"identifiers":["steam:110000117829c82","license:","xbl:2535428445779911","live:914801662046383"],"name":"Peraergold","ping":92},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":186,"identifiers":["steam:11000010582ce53","license:"],"name":"Danni Dank","ping":41},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":241,"identifiers":["steam:1100001097779e3","","xbl:2533275032997544","live:844428204995039"],"name":"Tony J.","ping":203},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":240,"identifiers":["steam:110000112553cd6","license:","xbl:2535471542971056","live:914801366308041"],"name":"Lassen","ping":60},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":150,"identifiers":["steam:110000110d1cebc","license:","live:844428721915290"],"name":"5D|155 Edward Johnson","ping":47},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":220,"identifiers":["steam:1100001186378bc","license:","xbl:2535439158130935","live:1759221955842916"],"name":"Sync","ping":81},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":215,"identifiers":["steam:11000010b2f22a8","license:"],"name":"Thomas W. | CIV-335","ping":50},{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":213,"identifiers":["steam:11000010b196656","license:"],"name":"Birac","ping":66}]

Comment: Lacks readability , can you properly specify what exactly you want? please define the actions & output you are expecting.

Comment: Post your json. but from what I can tell, you're overcomplicating your method for extracting data from the JSON file. When you run `json_decode` it returns an object. Try `print_r($players);` and it'll show you what you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the `http_build_query` function is to create a URL-encoded query string, there seems to be no need for this in your code. Your code creates an object from the JSON string but you are treating it like it's an array, you need to set the second parameter of the `json_decode()` function call to *TRUE* to have an array returned.

```
// use the second parameter to create an associative array from the JSON
$players = json_decode($data, true);
```

Assuming there is more than one player returned in the JSON use this as a starting point to build your table rows:

```
foreach($players as $player) {
  echo '<tr>'
  foreach($player as $key => $value) {
    echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>'
  }
  echo '</tr>'
}
```

If there are elements of the player array which you don't want to display then you can use the `array_keys()` function to get the keys and specify the fields to output in your code.

You should also keep in mind that your code is dependant on an external resource which may not always be available. The `file_get_contents()` function call will generate an exception if the provided URL is not available and your code should handle this scenario.

```
try {
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  if ($data === false) {
    // Handle the error
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Handle the exception
}
```

**UPDATE:** The JSON data you have provided doesn't match up with what you are trying to achieve. Each of the JSON items in the array only contains 5 properties: *endpoint*, *id*, *identifiers*, *name* & *ping*.

The following PHP code will parse the provided JSON file and display some of the information that I think you are looking for.

```
$json = file_get_contents('./players.json');

$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($json_data as $player_data) {
    // Initialise the steam id to an empty string in case one is not found
    $player_steam_id = "";
    // Find the steam id in the identifiers array
    if (array_key_exists("identifiers", $player_data)) {
        $steam_identifiers = [];
        foreach ($player_data["identifiers"] as $identifier_str)
            if (preg_match("/^steam:/i", $identifier_str, $m))
                $steam_identifiers[] = $identifier_str;
        if (!empty($steam_identifiers)) {
            $player_steam_id = $steam_identifiers[0];
        }
    }
    $player_id = $player_data["id"];
    $player_name = $player_data["name"];
    // Show what we have
    print( $player_id . " - " . $player_name . " - " . $player_steam_id . "\n" );
}
```

Comment: I thank you for the timely response but I am just extremely new to json data and I still cant get it the way I want.

Comment: Follow the suggestion to `print_r($players);` and add the result to your question.

Comment: Added the contents

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code to parse your data.

Comment: I also need identifiers[1]. Should I just repeat the line for 0?

Comment: I answered my own question Thank you so much for this!